# What does the javascript (insert name of object here) 'defaultChecked' do?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, default, checked

What does the javascript (insert name of object here) 'defaultChecked' do?

Comment: And what should be in the '(insert name of object here)'? I don't remember. Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The defaultChecked property returns
>   the default value of the checked
>   attribute.
>
> This property returns true if the
>   checkbox is checked by default,
>   otherwise it returns false.

Quoted from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_defaultchecked.asp).

Answer (score 0):

What don't you understand? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_defaultchecked.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe example will help? http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/cCpUu/

As you see if the checkbox has the "checked" attribute it will return `true` otherwise `false` - note however it's not affected by the "current" checked state of the checkbox.